# How to overwrite addEventListener in Firefox 3.x?

Tags: javascript, firefox, prototype, addeventlistener

im making a greasemonkey userscript which puts all kinds of shims and
polyfills in the page for old browsers.
the problem is that none of them seems to include anything to make the
third parameter of 'addEventListener' optional, and since webpages
usually omit it, it gives a "Not enough arguments." error everywhere.

i tried to overwrite it this way:

```
Element.prototype.oldaddEventListener = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(event,handler, placeholder) {
    if (!arguments[2]) {
        this.oldaddEventListener(event,handler, false);
        }
        else{
        this.oldaddEventListener(event,handler, placeholder);
        }

}
```

and now checking if it replaced the function on elements:

```
alert(document.querySelector("div").addEventListener)
```

alerts the original:

```
function addEventListener() {
    [native code]
}
```

checking the Element.prototype.addEventListener:

```
alert(Element.prototype.addEventListener)
```

shows the overwritten version.
so then i tried overwriting these:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener,
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener,
HTMLDivElement.prototype.addEventListener,
Object.prototype.addEventListener,
Node.prototype.addEventListener,
```

NONE of this worked. every of them shows to be overwritten when
alerted, but none of it affects the function of elements.
i searched in the firebug DOM inspector for any instances of it that
were still showing the original, and overwritten it in
'applicationCache', 'content', 'document', 'frames', 'parent', 'self'
and 'top'. obviously this didnt work either.

the userscript runs at 'document-start', and i checked that it runs
before any other script and before the  element even exists.
running the script manually after the page loaded also does nothing.
the only way i found to overwrite the function on elements is to
directly select that element and overwrite it on each and every
element one by one.

so my question is: how to overwrite the "addEventListener" function on
every element globally, in Firefox 3.x?

Comment: Firefox 3 is over a decade old. It's a very long time past any hope of getting security updates. You really shouldn't be using it.

Comment: im specifically making a userscript to polyfill/shim on older browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite bad what they did there...  Luckily they fixed it since then ;-)

```
var el1 = document.createElement('div');
var el2 = document.createElement('div');

el1.addEventListener === el2.addEventListener;
```

is `false` in FF 3.2...

This means that they were setting for every element its own version of the function (probably a bound version).

Given this, your only way is to catch all the elements and append to them your own version one by one.

One way is to overwrite the `document.createElement` method, but this will work only on elements that are created by scripts.
To catch the ones that in the markup, you could use a TreeWalker.

```js
function overwrite(target) {
  if (target._addEvent_overwritten) return; // do it only once
  // calling the Element.prototype.addEventListener throws an Error in FF3.x
  var prevAddEventListener = target.addEventListener;
  target.addEventListener = function(type, handler, options) {
    prevAddEventListener.call(this, type, handler, !!options);
  };
  target._addEvent_overwritten = true;
}
// catch in document.createElement  
// FF 3.x doesn't set the Document.prototype.createElement
var prevCreateElem = HTMLDocument.prototype.createElement;
HTMLDocument.prototype.createElement = function(type) {
  var elem = prevCreateElem.call(this, type);
  overwrite(elem);
  return elem;
};

// not only Elements do have this method...
overwrite(window);
overwrite(document);

// catch after Document has been generated
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // catch all Elements
  var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
    document.documentElement, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, null, false
  );
  while (walker.nextNode())
    overwrite(walker.currentNode);
});

// Tests

var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  this.textContent = 'clicked'
});
elem.textContent = 'click me (dynamic)';
document.body.appendChild(elem);

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('in-doc').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.textContent = 'clicked';
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="in-doc">click me (in markup)</div>
```

However this won't catch the ones in markup that receive event listeners before the DOMContentLoaded event fired.

For these, you will probably have to also overwrite all of `document.getElementById`, `document.querySelector`, `Element_instance.querySelector`, `NodeList` getters, `HTMLCollection` getters etc.
That's not a trivial task, and I unfortunately miss the incentives to do it all for this answer, since I only use this FF version from mozregression when searching about a bug, but at least you get the idea.

Comment: thank you for this, i just thought there would be a single prototype or something to overwrite. where does it come from for all the elements then? creating an element after overwriting it  in Element.prototype and EventTarget.prototype still didnt seem to give them the new one

Comment: Indeed and that's exactly what this answer is saying. Two elements that will share the same prototype chain will have different addEventListener methods. I didn't checked the source code but it is very probably set internally to a bound function that we don't have access to. That's why the only way is to override manually the methods of every instance...

Answer (score 3):

`addEventListener` is inherited from the `EventTarget` prototype, not `Element`.

```js
var placeToReplace;
if (window.EventTarget && EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener) {
  placeToReplace = EventTarget;
} else {
  placeToReplace = Element;
}

placeToReplace.prototype.oldaddEventListener = placeToReplace.prototype.addEventListener;
placeToReplace.prototype.addEventListener = function(event, handler, placeholder) {
  console.log("calling substitute");
  if (arguments.length < 3) {
    this.oldaddEventListener(event, handler, false);
  } else {
    this.oldaddEventListener(event, handler, placeholder);
  }
}
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("foo");
});
```

```html
<div>Click me</div>
```

Comment: i tried that too, its listed in the question. still doesnt seem to overwrite it on elements in the page

Comment: it would need to work specifically on old browsers which dont support the third parameter being optional. this and the Element.prototype works on newer browsers, but it was probably different back then

Comment: I've added conditional code that will check whether `EventTarget` exists. I think this should work as an appropriate polyfill.

Comment: Element inherits from EventTarget, so setting an `addEventListener` method on the Element's prototype will make this version available to Element instances. What OP does should work.

Comment: @Kaiido Indeed, if I replace my conditional with just `PlaceToReplace = Element` it works in a modern browser.