# How to call `getEventListeners` in GreaseMonkey

Tags: javascript, copy, listener, greasemonkey

I'm try to write a user script in GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey. I want to delete all `copy` listeners. But it seems that `getEventListeners` is undefined in the sandbox.

I've tried `unsafeWindow`, but the `getEventListeners` is still missing.

Is there a way to call it in the GreaseMonkey environment?

Or are there any methods can I remove all `copy` listeners?

Comment: It's a devtools command which is only available in devtools console. What you can do is to run the script at `document-start` and overwrite addEventListener in unsafeWindow and just ignore all calls for `copy` event. Depending on the actual site it may be possible to use a simpler method based on stopping event propagation.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. It works. I used the scripts in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57437878/535374) to override it.